# How can I improve this method that removes duplicates from an ArrayList so that it will be more effecient than O(n2)

Tags: java

This method removes duplicate objects from a list that have the same address field. it works for me at the moment. But I am upgrading my application and I am expecting my ArrayLists to get bigger. (200+ objects)

I am worried it might be too slow for comparing 200 records for example, since It is O(n2)

How can I improve it.

```
public static ArrayList<Place> removeDuplicates(ArrayList<Place> masterList) {
    ArrayList<Place> tempList = new ArrayList<Place>(masterList);
    for (int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++) {
        String address = tempList.get(i).getAddress();
        for (int j = 0; j < tempList.size(); j++) {
            String address2 = tempList.get(j).getAddress();
            if (address.equalsIgnoreCase(address2) && i != j) {
                tempList.remove(tempList.get(j));
            }
        }

    }
    return tempList;
}
```

**edit**

Thanks all for the unanimous answers. I have a finasl question. What goes in the hashcode and equals methods when I over ride them?

Comment: Don't remove items from `ArrayList` without an iterator.

Comment: Don't improve it before you've proven (with metrics) that this is a bottleneck in your application. (*Except, of course, following @MarounMaroun's advice*).

Answer (score 5):

Make sure the instances produce a good hashcode and use `HashSet` or `LinkedHashSet` (if you want to preserve order):

```
 return new ArrayList<Place>(new LinkedHashSet<Place>(masterList));
```

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is overwriting the `hashcode` and  `equals` methods and generate a Set from your list.

In this way is java that takse care of removing duplicate elements in the list, and not you.

Comment: what goes in the hascode and equals methods when I over ride them?

Comment: You can use Eclipse (Source >> Generate hashcode() and equals()... ) or Nebeans to automatically generate the code for you, or alternatively can take a look at Effective Java 2nd: `Item 8: Obey the general contract when overriding equals`
and `Item 9 - Always override hashCode when you override equals`

Comment: Thanks. I have generated it for the address field only. i will try it out

Answer (score 1):

```
public static ArrayList<Place> removeDuplicates(ArrayList<Place> masterList) {
    Set<Place> temp = new HashSet<Place>();
    for(Place place : masterList) {
        if(!temp.add(place)) {
            masterList.remove(place);
        }
    }

    return masterList;
}
```

Comment: The objects may not be equal even if they have the same address field

Comment: With a definied `equals` method you have to decide yourself when you declare the objects as equal.

Answer (score 1):

Your masterlist of places

```
    List<Place> masterList = new ArrayList<Place>();
    masterList.add(new Place());
    masterList.add(new Place());
    masterList.add(new Place());
```

Removing the duplicates by adding to set "s"

```
   Set<Place> s = new TreeSet<Place>(new Comparator<Place>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Place o1, Place o2) {                
            return o1.getAddress().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getAddress());                
       }           
    });

    s.addAll(masterList);
```

Printing your result

```
    List<Object> res = Arrays.asList(s.toArray());
     for (Object object : res) {
         Place place = (Place)object;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `equals` and `hashcode` defined for `Place` object, just create `HashSet` from arraylist, and then create arraylist from set.